# How to find different number of distinct integers from given set of number

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> How many different integers can be expressed as the sum of $3$ distinct numbers from the 
>   set $\{3, 10, 17, 24, 31, 38, 45, 52\}$?

Could someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hints

- The answer would be the same starting with $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$
- What is the smallest number you can make?
- What is the largest?
- Can you make every integer in-between?

If a number in the second set is $n$ then an equivalent number in the first set is $7n-4$.  So if a number which is the sum of three distinct numbers from the second set is $s$ then an equivalent sum from the first set is $7s-12$.

So if you ignore the first hint, then the sums you can make must be $12$ less than a multiple of $7$. Can you make them all between the smallest and largest possible?

Comment: smallest number will be 30 and largest will be 135

Comment: @PK28: OK on the first set - you cannot make $31,32,33,34,35,36$ (why not?). But can you make $37, 44, \ldots , 128$?   Or using the second set, the smallest is $6$ and the largest is $21$: can you make $7,8,\ldots , 20$?  In either case, how many numbers can you make?